# Facebook Uncaught ReferenceError: CommentAdminPanelController is not defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

When I linked facebook comments social plugin to my website, I am getting this error in Chrome console. Can you explain me, what does it mean? 
Screenshot: http://www.up-img.cz/files/d3d7c6194af766ca594a465a10f0665227ab5c97e3962ac0212d235fb3501472/linked.png
When I google this error, it will not search anything. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Code? `CommentAdminPanelController` doesn't seem to be a Facebook-side variable (personally I have never seen it)

Comment: @AdamAzad this is not from my website, it is from facebook. You can see it here on facebook site: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=309599029178359&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D40%23cb%3Df2c822f5fc%26domain%3Dradimsulak.blogoo.eu%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fradimsulak.blogoo.eu%252Ff1165afb44%26relation%3Dparent.parent&colorscheme=light&href=http%3A%2F%2Fradimsulak.blogoo.eu%2F%3Fpost%3D41&locale=en_US&numposts=5&sdk=joey&skin=light&width=550